# Comparing perfomance of standard volumes vs provisional iops volumes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, provisioned-iops

Here's a question which bugs me:

I'm trying compare standard AWS volumes with provisioned IOPS volumes in terms of perfomance. In AWS documentation, it's stated that IOPS instances are designed to deliver IO performance within 10% of desired capacity.

What I'd like to know is this: let's say, I'm creating 2000 IOPS volume. How much faster is this when compared to standard AWS volume?

Comment: Base EBS performance depends on how you set it (single volume vs RAID) up and how noisy your tenants are. This [blog post](http://blog.scalyr.com/2012/10/16/a-systematic-look-at-ec2-io/) benchmarks EBS.

Comment: Yes, I've actually tried the RAID stuff, and I thought that provisioned IOPS could be an other way to go about it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Raid used to be the only option, but provisioned IOPS might be a better choice. Its not hard to set up a test of both and see what provides the best value for your workload.